# In Skyrim, what is the third official High Res Texture Pack module for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have quite an old machine, and I am trying to work out which modules I should load at launch in order to reduce stress on the GPU. Depending on what they do, I can make a more informed decision on the trade-off of graphics vs performance.

I noticed, after downloading the official Skyrim High Res Texture Pack, that in the loading screen the pack is divided into three:

- HighResTexturePack01.esp
- HighResTexturePack02.esp
- HighResTexturePack03.esp

These modules can, if needs be, selected separately. I've read that the first is for weapons and armour, and the second for the environment. What is the third for?

Comment: Honestly, why not just load that third and see what it does?

Comment: My experience was that the high res texture on OldRim was actually slower than Skyrim Special Edition. My computer is an i5 laptop with 960M GPU.

Comment: @Nelson that's very interesting. Seeing as my machine only runs a 6870, I doubt that it'll be able to run the Special Edition, even though it's perfectly good for Oldrim.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas see the accepted answer.

Comment: @Nelson I should point out that it's really a case of "YMMV". My computer cannot run Skyrim SE [I've tried it, and its unplayable] whereas the high-res texture pack works great with my graphics card. So it's all relative :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer -

> Its for DG and DB, it also contains vanilla HD creatures similar to
> the first.

In more detail:

> - No Hearthfire textures.
> - Some Dawnguard textures (mostly related to creatures)
> - Dragonborn textures!
> - Some base vanilla game textures, such as new high res face textures for all races and sixes, as well as textures for common creatures
>   (bears, deer, elk, so on)!

It's mainly for the expansions. This is the reason why it was hard to tell exactly what it does and why loading it doesn't necessarily give an answer: if those packs aren't installed, it will be a lot harder to notice.

From:

http://www.gamesas.com/patch-highrestexturepack03-esp-t309726.html